# Function in EV3 Basic

Tags: ev3, programming

I have been programming in basic for ~30 years. I want a translation of the following code into EV3 Basic:

```
function index( x , y )

  return x + y * ( maxx , + 1

end function

sub look

  for i = 0 to 5

    motor.start( "bc" , 75 , 75 , false )

    program.delay( .025 sec )

  next i

  motor.stop( "bc")

end sub
```

How do you do this in ev3basic?

Comment: I don't think this is something we can solve, shouldn't this be moved to SO?